# C# TCP client does not connect to IP Adress

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, wifi

Hello I am using Android phone Wi-Fi hotspot to create network, then using C# to connect to this hotspot.

The ipadress of hotspot is: 192.168.43.1.

First I connect to Wi-Fi hotspot by laptop Wi-Fi.

Now I am using C# code:

```
private void connectToServer()
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

                tcpclnt.Connect("192.168.43.1", 8001);
                // use the ipaddress as in the server program

                Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");

                String str = Console.ReadLine();
                Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

                ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);
                Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

                stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

                byte[] bb = new byte[100];
                int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);

                for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                    Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));

                tcpclnt.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.Message);
            }
        }
```

But I always get this exception:

> Error..... No connection could be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it 192.168.43.1:8001

Hi, after some searching, i found the port not found in my machine, by using netstat:

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         admin-PC:65298         TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         admin-PC:65299         TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         admin-PC:65300         TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         admin-PC:65301         TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         admin-PC:65302         TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         admin-PC:65304         TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         admin-PC:65305         TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49165        admin-PC:49436         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49263        admin-PC:49264         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49264        admin-PC:49263         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49265        admin-PC:49266         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49266        admin-PC:49265         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49436        admin-PC:49165         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49559        admin-PC:49560         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49560        admin-PC:49559         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51477        admin-PC:51478         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51478        admin-PC:51477         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:55300        admin-PC:55301         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:55301        admin-PC:55300         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61797        admin-PC:61798         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61798        admin-PC:61797         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61800        admin-PC:61801         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61801        admin-PC:61800         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61807        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61809        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61810        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61811        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61813        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63271        admin-PC:63272         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63272        admin-PC:63271         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63274        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63275        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63279        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63284        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63304        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63351        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63353        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63354        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63355        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63356        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63357        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63358        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63359        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63367        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63368        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63370        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63373        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63377        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63378        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63385        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63386        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63387        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63388        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63389        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63396        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63462        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:64544        admin-PC:49333         TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:64545        admin-PC:64546         TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:64555        admin-PC:5037          TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:64557        admin-PC:5037          TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:64558        admin-PC:5037          TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:64919        admin-PC:5037          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:65303        admin-PC:5563          SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.34:64035     43.239.149.131:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.12.2:63262     192.168.12.101:22469   ESTABLISHED
```

I still read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275597/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it-127-0?rq=1) but still get this error.
Here is my android code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

Handler updateConversationHandler;

Thread serverThread = null;

private TextView text;

public static final int SERVERPORT = 8001;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

    updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

    this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    this.serverThread.start();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader input;

    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

        try {
            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {
                String read = input.readLine();
                updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class updateUIThread implements Runnable {

    private String msg;

    public updateUIThread(String str) {
        this.msg = str;
    }

    @Override
    public  void run() {
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: *What* exception do you get?

Comment: Error..... No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.43.1:8001

Comment: That's quite clear. The target is not accepting the connection.

Comment: i updated question, plz take a look, thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the exception you are getting, the problem is not in your code, it is in the connection itself. This can be a firewall issue or the process listening on a different port.

EDIT: The OP has found that the problem he had was in the IIS and that **resetting the IIS solved his problem**. To reset IIS, you can do this either manually or through command prompt:
Run (Win+R) -> open cmd (with admin privileges) -> type "iisreset" (without "")

Comment: i cant find the port in cmd, i updated question, plz take a look, thanks you

Comment: I am by no means expert for this, but I would try the following: 
Check your permissions in AndroidManifest.xml for: "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>" and add it if it is not there.

Comment: Hi, i found the solution is reset iis, may be my machine use bootcamp so doesn't enable iis service, after reset it easy to connect to host :)

Comment: Glad you found the solution! Would you like to write an answer to the question yourself in order to help others searching for this problem in the future? EDIT: After a couple of hours I have added your solution to my answer. If you want to answer it yourself, let me know and I will delete mine.

Comment: yeah. Thank you, i have busy in job, so now read your post. t.y man